# Concatenating split quotes

Tags: python, regex

I have a large file (f) with a lot of dialogue. I need a regex that will concatenate the split quotes (i.e. "Hello," Josh said enthusiastically, "I have a question!"), but not delete the middle portion. So, for this example, the output would be, "Hello, I have a question!" and then "Josh said enthusiastically" would be retained somewhere. I think I am on the right track, but haven't found something that works for these specifications. Here is the code I have already tried out:

```
for line in f:
  re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', line)
  output_file.write(line)
```

and

```
split = re.compile(r'''
                (,\")                
                (.*?)                
                (,)                  
                ( )                  
                (")''', re.VERBOSE)  

for line in f:
  m = split_quote.match(split)
  if m:
    output_file.write(m.group(1) + m.group(5))
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem with these solutions than "they don't work"?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "be retained somewhere"?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
/(".+?)"(.+?),\s+?"(.+?[.?!]+")/g
```

Then replace the capture groups in this order:

```
$1 $3$2.
```

like so:

```
m.group(1) + " " + m.group(3) + m.group(2) + "."
```

### Example:

> "Hello," Josh said enthusiastically, "I have a question!"

to

> "Hello, I have a question!" Josh said enthusiastically.

### Explanation:

[http://bsite.cc/inoD/Screen%20Shot%202017-01-18%20at%206.01.22%20PM.png](https://regexper.com/#%2F(%22.%2B%3F)%22(.%2B%3F)%2C%5Cs%2B%3F%22(.%2B%3F%5B.%3F!%5D%2B%22)%2Fg)

1. First part matches a `"`, and then any characters until it sees another quote.

   - `"Hello,`"**|** Josh said enthusiastically, "I have a question!"
2. Second part matches text in the middle of the quotes, until it reaches a comma (also matches whitespace after comma and the first quote)

   - "Hello," `Josh said enthusiastically`, **|** "I have a question!"
3. Third group matches until the next quote

   - "Hello," Josh said enthusiastically, "`I have a question!"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=\")([^\s].*?[^\s])(?=\")|(?<=\")\s(.*?)\s(?=\")
```

The regex above will match these two strings: `Hello,` and `I have a question!` in group 1, which will make you able to print them together. The same regex will distinguish this portion `Josh said enthusiastically,` and match it in group 2 which will be handy in case you've decided to use it later.

Check out demo: https://regex101.com/r/m7nqnu/1

This is a working Python code:

```
import re
text = '''"Hello," Josh said enthusiastically, "I have a question!"'''
print ('Group 1: ')
for m in re.finditer(r"(?<=\")([^\s].*?[^\s])(?=\")|(?<=\")\s(.*?)\s(?=\")", text):
    if m.group(1) is not None:
        print('%s ' % (m.group(1)))
print ('<br />Group 2: ')
for m in re.finditer(r"(?<=\")([^\s].*?[^\s])(?=\")|(?<=\")\s(.*?)\s(?=\")", text):
    if m.group(2) is not None:
        print('%s ' % (m.group(2)))
```

Output:

```
Group 1: Hello, I have a question! 
Group 2: Josh said enthusiastically,
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are no quotes within quotes, and all quotes properly match, and the phrase always consists of two quoted parts with an unquoted part in the middle:

```
parts = [x.strip() for x in re.findall(r'"([^"]+)', text)]
print(parts[0] + " " + parts[2])
# Hello, I have a question!
print(parts[1])
# Josh said enthusiastically,
```